# curl succeeds but wget gives 502 error for a request on custom port

Tags: linux, curl, wget

```
$ curl http://localhost:7810/test
hello world!
$ 
$ 
$ wget http://localhost:7810/test
--2011-09-27 07:04:06--  http://localhost:7810/test
Resolving <snipped>
Connecting to <snipped> connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 502 Bad Gateway
2011-09-27 07:04:06 ERROR 502: Bad Gateway.

$
```

It seems that wget is looking at port `80` even though I specified `7810`. How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a config file, possibly `~/.wgetrc`, where a proxy is specified.